# Empty JSOB object vs NULL as column value in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have tried to dig the vastness of **WWW** but haven't found a meaningful answer to my questions.

What is the best practice when dealing with `JSONB` columns? Should the default value be an empty `JSON` object or is the correct way setting the default to `NULL`?

What is the size implications of setting the empty object? Empty `JSON` object equals **2** bytes so in theory, **1 000 000 000** records would end up costing **1GB** of storage.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use `NULL` values sparingly.

`NULL` is designed to mean "unknown". So if you want to express "I don't know what attributes there are", use `NULL`. If you want to say "I know that there are no attributes", use an empty `jsonb`.

That way, you have the best odds of ending up with simpler SQL queries that express your intention naturally.